# Nested cartesian product of Haskell lists

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension, cartesian-product

I would like to make a method where I could give it a list of lengths and it would return all combinations of cartesian coordinates up to those lengths. Easier to explain with an example:

```
cart [2,5]
Prelude> [ [0,0],[0,1],[0,2],[0,3],[0,4],[1,0],[1,1],[1,2],[1,3],[1,4] ]

cart [2,2,2]
Prelude> [ [0,0,0],[0,0,1],[0,1,0],[0,1,1],[1,0,0],[1,0,1],[1,1,0],[1,1,1] ]
```

A simple list comprehension won't work because I don't know how long the lists are going to be. While I love Haskell's simplicity for many problems, this is one that I could write procedurally (in C or something) in 5 minutes whereas Haskell gives me an aneurysm!

A solution to this specific problem would help me out a lot; I'd also love to hear about your thought processes when tackling stuff like this.

Comment: Wow, thanks Kenny and Dave. I never thought to throw a recursive call into the list comprehension definition - very cool. The version using map and fold is great. I try to use the higher order functions when I can think of a way, so this is a great example to study!

Comment: as long as you're using higher order functions, know that it should not be cryptic. and using the right functions help get there, `sequence` is what you need here.

Comment: Thank you yairchu for both the concise and clear solution and for introducing me to hoogle. How did I do anything without this?!

Comment: for another interesting tool by ndmitchell check out hlint. it suggests a further shortening to my solution as newacct pointed out.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This can be solved recursively. First, the [Cartesian product of nothing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_product#Nullary_Cartesian_product) is {∅}:

```
cart [] = [[]]
```

(Or define just the 1-element form if the empty product is invalid:

```
cart [x] = [[i] | i <- [0 .. x-1]]
```

)

Then, the Cartesian product of `x:xs` can be written as

```
cart (x:xs) = [i:rest | i <- [0 .. x-1], rest <- cart xs]
```

---

In general, if you what to write a function *f* that requires the list's length *N*, try to think of a way to make *f(N)* depends on smaller lists e.g. *f(N - 1)* only, then solve the base case *f(0)* or *f(1)* etc. This transforms the problem into a recursion that can be easily solved.

Answer (score 13):

Umm..

```
cart = sequence . map (enumFromTo 0 . subtract 1)
```

It's reasonable to expect that a `[[a]] -> [[a]]` function doing what we expect already exists in the library. So if one is not familiar with `sequence`, finding it is a simple matter of [hoogling](http://haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%5b%5ba%5d%5d+-%3E+%5b%5ba%5d%5d) it.

**Edit:** as newacct pointed out:

```
cart = mapM (enumFromTo 0 . subtract 1)
```

This can also be found by feeding the previous solution to [HLint](http://community.haskell.org/~ndm/hlint/).

Comment: `cart = mapM (enumFromTo 0 . subtract 1)`

Comment: @newacct: nice. btw hlint suggests this as well :)

Comment: Wow, it's funny how ingrained `sequence . map (...)` is as the answer to this kind of question, since it was my initial reaction too.

Answer (score 7):

I bet your procedural solution would involve recursion. Our Haskell solution will involve recursion too.

So, recursion. First the recursive case.

```
cart (c : cs) = [i : r | i <- [0 .. c-1], r <- rcart]
  where rcart = cart cs
```

Here we're just saying that for each possible initial co-ordinate, and each possible combination of cartesian co-ordinates from the remaining lengths, we do the obvious thing of combining the co-ordinate with the remaining co-ordinates.

Then the base case.

```
cart [] = [[]]
```

You might think `cart [] = []`. I did at first. But think about what the recursive case requires from the base case.